# Why does Safari add a weird extension to YouTube links?

Tags: macbook-pro, safari, youtube, web-browser

When I click on a YouTube video the browser always adds this extension to the link: "**&frags=pl%2Cwn**".

**Example** links:

- Normal link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Example123
- Link in Safari: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Example123&frags=pl%2Cwn

This problem only occurs when I use my MacBook Pro in Safari (version 12.0.2).

Both links work, I've tried it on multiple computers / different web browsers and as far as I see there's absolutely no difference.

When I click on a video in YouTube the link gets added automatically, but I can remove it manually and the page just loads again without the extension (like a refresh of the page).

My questions are:

- Why does this happen?
- Has anybody else encountered this problem (Maybe it's a user-specific problem)?

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Comment: @nohillside Added the questions, should be clear now.

Comment: It isn’t user specific, if you search for “frags=pl%2Cwn” you can see that there are a bunch of YouTube video links that have that in them. Not sure what it is, but it happens to other people.

Comment: Do you have some sort of YouTube related extension loaded?  I've tested in all my versions of Safari and none have that URL format.

Comment: It's almost definitely youtube/google that does this, not Safari. I can't make out what it does, but this javascript file refers to the "frags" query 3 times (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/desktop_polymer-vfl8ahXk7/desktop_polymer.js). So it's intended, and not a "problem".

Comment: Google is a massive enterprise with thousands of servers to serve you content closest to your location. Is the problem simply sometimes you get a redirection url or does this somehow break something else. This seems a little off topic due to the avoid asking about things where [there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Your Safari browser is not “adding an extension“ to the links.  This is known as a “parameter” and is either in the webpage’s HTML, or possibly being added by a browser extension that you have loaded, if any, such as tampermonkey.    The webpage HTML or Safari’s settings may be showing you a different (or truncated) URL/address/URI in the status bar or “tool tip”.

Comment: @bmike Where then should I ask this question?

Comment: By "Safari" he prob means, "Why is Google adding the parameter when I use Safari, but not on other browsers?"

Answer (score 1):

The Youtube webapp is adding that to the link (or URL, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL).

The characters after the question mark in the link is the query string (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). It's one of the ways data can be passed to the server. The "v" parameter specifies which video to show. The ampersand ("&") separates parameters.

I can't find any reference as to what the "frags" parameter does. "%2C" is a comma (",") that's been percent-encoded (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), so that part is setting the "frags" parameter to "pl,wn".

It's definitely not a problem. Everything is fine.